# How to read MSMQ from OSB

Tags: msmq, osb

I need to create a proxy service that will listen from MSMQ (Microsoft Messaging Queue ) .May I know what transport protocol/ adapter should i use to make this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Is that Oracle Service Bus? You would need an MSMQ adaptor - MSMQ uses it's own transport protocol (plus HTTP/S & RPC). It looks like OSB only has a Websphere MQ adaptor.

Comment: Hi John , thanks for the reply .Yes it's for Oracle Service Bus and I'm using version 10.3 which only supports Websphere MQ Adaptor and JMS . I tried a lot of search from the internet but I can't find an MSMQ adaptor for OSB :( ..Hope someone can provide the MSMQ adaptor. Thanks

Comment: Would be impressed if you found one.